# Loop through array and pass value to mysql query php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have the following JSON object

```
[
  {
    "var1": "ID001",
    "var2": "ROY",
    "var3": "16"
  },
  {
    "var1": "ID002",
    "var2": "MARK",
    "var3": "15"
  },
  {
    "var1": "ID003",
    "var2": "PETER",
    "var3": "15"
  }
]
```

I want to loop through the JSON and pass a value to following MySQL query

```
$select_data=mysqli_query($connsow, "select * from salary where col1 = '$var1' and col2 = '$var2'");
```

Below is my code, I used a foreach loop but it always selects the first value in the JSON object. I can't loop through entire JSON and pass the value to query

```
foreach($rows as $item) { 
    $cust_ord_no = $item['var1'];
    $cont_n = $item['var2'];
    $select_data=mysqli_query($connsow, "select * from test where col1 = '$var1' and col2 = '$var2'");
}
```

Comment: Do `json_decode($json, true)` to convert into array. then loop on the array.

Comment: Also, your query is open to SQL injection. Please use prepared statements

Comment: Hey first build Where clause in the for-each loop then append that where clause to the SQL outside of the for-each.

Comment: @Gajanan Kolpuke can help to going about appending

Comment: @kanishka I have added the answer, kindly refer that, Actually you are trying to access $var1 direct which is not defined.

Comment: @kanishka I have updated answer, plz check again

Comment: Incidentally, executing a query inside a loop is often a rather inefficient idea.

Answer (score 0):

- First convert the JSON to array usng [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function with second parameter set to `true`. Then, you can loop through the array.

Do the following:

```
$rows = json_decode($rows, true);
```

- Most importantly, your query is **Open** to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308). Please use [Prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: @kanishka what do you mean by same result. After running the select query, I don't see you doing anything with the query result set

Comment: query execute only for the first json. the last two json ID - ID002 and ID ID003 i dont get the result

Comment: I hope you are using correct variable in query.It should be `$cust_ord_no` instead of `$var1` and so on

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access key with name, instead of that, you have to use a variable which you have defined just before SQL.

```
$rows = json_decode($strJSON, true);

$select_data = [];
foreach( $rows  as $item ) {
    $cust_ord_no = $item['var1'];
    $cont_n = $item['var2'];
    $strSQL = "select * from test where col1 = '$cust_ord_no' and col2 = '$cont_n'";
    $select_data[] =mysqli_query($connsow, $strSQL);
}
```

Comment: sorry that was typp im using the variable name but still same only get result from the first json value

Comment: $select_data[] = mysqli_query($connsow, $strSQL);  And $select_data = [] array at the top of foreach.